# Post request to create coupons does not save data with sequelize postgres

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

I have a problem with the following request. And that is that it runs successfully, but when I check the data in my database, the Coupons table saves the data but CouponProducts has not saved that information. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you very much for your help, I will be attentive if you need more context.

```
  async createCoupon(couponData) {
    const transaction = await models.Coupons.sequelize.transaction()

    try {
      const coupon = await models.Coupons.create(
        {
          id: uuid4(),
          couponCode: couponData.couponCode,
          discount: couponData.discount,
        },
        { transaction }
      )

      const couponId = coupon.id
      const couponProducts = Promise.all(
        couponData.productIds.map(async (product) => {
          if (product.productType === 'Department') {
            const department = await models.Products.findOne({
              where: {
                departmentId: product.departmentId,
              },
            })
            return {
              couponId: couponId,
              departmentId: product.departmentId,
              tourId: null,
              productType: product.productType,
              productName: department.dataValues.productName,
            }
          } else if (product.productType === 'Tour') {
            const tour = await models.Products.findOne({
              where: {
                tourId: product.tourId,
              },
            })
            return {
              couponId: couponId,
              departmentId: null,
              tourId: product.tourId,
              productType: product.productType,
              productName: tour.dataValues.productName,
            }
          } else {
            throw new Error(
              'Invalid product type. Use "Department" or "Tour" as product type.'
            )
          }
        })
      )
      console.log(couponProducts)
      await models.CouponProducts.bulkCreate(couponProducts, { transaction })
      await transaction.commit()
      return coupon
    } catch (error) {
      await transaction.rollback()
      throw error
    }
  }
```

The console.log(couponProducts) printout is

```
Promise { <pending> }
```

The execution of the entire request is successful, but the array transaction is not saved in the database. I don't know if the transaction accompanying bulkCreate is working.

Answer (score 0):

You should wait for the `couponProducts` result first by adding `await`:

```js
const couponProducts = await Promise.all(
```

then you will get Sequelize model instances instead of pending promises